# Xamarin design and source tab not showing

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, layout, tabs

I'm new in Xamarin. I have a problem that design and source tab not showing.I already tried right click  at file `axml`(solution explorer) and select view designer,but design interface not showed up.Then, I tried go to tools->options->XAML Designer then disable and enable XAML again but still design and source tab not showed.Hope you guys can help me solve this problem.Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: why not reset window ?

Comment: what do you mean reset window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new on xamarin so that I'm  make a mistakes.A message pop up and i accidentally disable extension "Xamarin Android Designer".

"[image: extension android designer disable]

to enable the extension go to tools-> extensions and updates..
after that enable xamarin android designer.

[image]